# Should ViewModel respond to each ProperyChanged event or is chunking better?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Here is the Question: 
**In cases where my model is a collection of other model objects, that may all be changed by some calculation, is it better not to use PropertyChanged per model item rather have a PropertyChanged at the parent level?**

Suppose I have my MVVM in WPF:

Model:

```
public class Model
{
     public IEnumerable<IItemModel> Items{ get;}
}

public class IItemModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     private int m_value;
     public int Value{ 
        get{ return m_value; }
        set{
             m_value = value;
             NotifyPropertyChanged(()=>Value);
        }
     }
}
```

And in ViewModel

```
// BaseViewModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged etc
public class MyViewModel: BaseViewModel     
{
    public MyViewModel(){
        var items = new Model.Items
        Items = new MyObservableColelction<ItemViewModel>(item => new ItemsViewModel(item), items);

    }

    public MyObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get ; set; }
}
```

Here, MyObservableColelction is some implementation of IObservableCollection that has its factory function that is passed as an Action that takes IItemModel and creates and add a ItemViewModel.

And finally the view (Xaml) is binding to the Items property which is not important here.

From MVVM and architecture this is fine. However I think about performance, suppose IItemModel::Value is calculated property, and all Items in model are calculated, is it better to deffer the property changed per item and maybe have One single property changed in the Model class?
It will reduce the amount of firing PropertyChanged Which in some cased I have 1000 of them.

Is it make sense, and how much of optimization is it?

Comment: Are you binding to the `Value` of each `ItemViewModel`? If you are then how are you going to let the binding target know about the change? Also, you are concerned about the `PropertyChanged` events but not concerned that you are creating an extra 1000 item viewmodels to begin with?

Comment: here I create the binding of Value from model layer to the View model, and will register to the PropertyChanged event: item => new ItemsViewModel(item). As for the second part, I actually do concern about this, and this is a major debate in my team, should it be wrapped as view model or should not, because in pure MVVM I should, but I believe it is a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 0):

The view which is binding to the model objects in the view model is against the Separation of Concern aspect which MVVM can give you. Your view will depend on the model which is used in the view model.

The amount of propertychanged causing a problem is rather unlikely unless you have a very special situation. Even in that case the root cause could a wrong approach in the solution rather than the property changed mechanism.

WPF/Windows is an event driven system and it can handle many events without an issue. If I were you, I would try to stick on with the pattern as much as possible.